# Duplicated messages reading via flink savepoints

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, savepoints

I'm trying to use Apache Flink 1.6.0 to read some messages from a kafka topic, transform them and finally send them to another kafka topic. I use savepoints to save the state of the application in case of cancellation and restating. The problem is that I have duplication in reading the messages after restart. The kafka version is 011. Thanks for any helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, it's necessary to pass `Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE` when setting up the kafka producer. See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-011) for more details concerning data loss and duplication when working with Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I pass the Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE parameter to the producer, I get this error message: "Pending record count must be zero at this point: 1"

Comment: The error was because of I set the "value.serializer" to "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" instead of "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"